# What is difference between $_var and $var

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I want to know, Is there any difference between these or not ?

```
class Classname
{
  private $_var;

  public function __construct($test)
  {
      $this->_var = $test;
  }

}
```

And

```
class Classname
{
  private $var;

  public function __construct($test)
  {
      $this->var = $test;
  }

}
```

If there is the difference, So when should I use this kine of variable? `$_var`

Comment: In the old days of PHP 4, when PHP didn't have property/method visibility; a property with a leading underscore was used to indicate that the property should be treated as private.... a convention that some people still retain in PHP 5

Comment: They have different names... that's it. It's a common convention to use a leading underscore in private class member names though.

Comment: @MarkBaker Why don't you post that [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32992713/what-is-difference-between-var-and-var#comment53810120_32992713) as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the old days of `PHP 4`, when PHP didn't have property/method
>   visibility; a property with a leading underscore was used to indicate
>   that the **property should be treated as private**, a convention that
>   some people still retain in PHP 5 - Mark Baker

---

In `php` `_` is a valid character variable name, you can use it as you would any other character.

`$_var` is the same as `$var`

---

**Tip:**
`$_` in Perl means the `default variable`, or in other words the `topic`.

Answer (score 3):

From [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

So the answer is **no**, there is no difference. `$_var` and `$var` are equally valid variable names.

And, as noted by other users in comments, a leading underscore can be used *as convention* to sign that a class property is a private/protected property, but that's not mandatory.